# Mongoose: how to find 3 words in any order and in any place in the string? (SQL 3 like with and)

Tags: regex, filter, mongoose

I cannot find a way to find a row where has ALL the 3 words (or more) with a regexp:

example

```
input words: "comp abc 300"
should match: "abcdef compres 300" and "ascompr zazabcd 9300"
```

I have a loop at the moment with a regexp that returns this:

```
(.*comp.*)(.*abc.*)(.*300.*)
```

but only matches in this order. I would like it to match in every order like in the example

it's just like 3 like with and between in them in SQL.

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Positive lookahead is what you need:

```
(?=.*comp)(?=.*abc)(?=.*300).*
```

More info at http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 0):

I've created a Node function that encapsulates it:

```
// Will add a full-text regexp search to a query
// can be used like this:
//   var query = myModel.model.find();
//   addFullTextSearch( query, "firstName", mySearchString );


function addFullTextSearch( query, paramName, searchString ) {
    if (searchString) {
        var r = "";
        var sss = searchString.split(" ");
        if (sss.length<=1) {            // only one word
            r = sss[0];
        } else {
            // result should look like this: (?=.*comp)(?=.*abc)(?=.*300).*
            for (var s in sss) {
                r += "(?=.*" + sss[s] + ")";
            }
            r += ".*";
        }
        query.where(paramName).regex(new RegExp(r, 'i'));       // "i" for case insensitivity
    }
}  // addFullTextSearch
```

Comment: I think this should be a comment to the answer?

Comment: I wanted it to be a comment, but I can't because I'm just starting. This reputation thing is really annoying... how does one start??